# bulk aws iam delete-login-profile

Tags: amazon-iam

I have an account in AWS that I want to block access to the console from some users (more than 50 users).
It's can be achieve using aws-cli by running this `aws iam delete-login-profile --user-name <name>` but I don't want to do it manually one by one, there is a way to do it in bulk (using CSV file etc.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it that way:

**Exporting all users to .csv:**

```
if aws iam list-users --output text --query 'Users[*].[UserName]' > users.csv
then
  echo "Users list exported successfully"
else
  echo "Export failed"
fi
```

**And then:**

```
#!/bin/bash
for n in $(cat users.csv )
do
    aws iam delete-login-profile --user-name "${n}"
echo "Deleting login profile for ${n}"
done < users.csv
```